# Legal way to pay for an MP3 that best supports the artist?

Tags: mp3

Been recently buying MP3s from various artists. I quite like MP3s over streaming as its at least a physical file that I have for my purchase.

However, it seems as the world has moved to streaming, it's harder to find an official MP3 purchase for most songs. Amazon Music seems to do many downloads but I worry what cut the artist actually gets from a big company like Amazon.

For a particular example, take the recent song Tones and I - Dance Monkey. Their link page is https://tonesandi.lnk.to/DanceMonkeyYT and has a whole bunch of various links to press. Blimey!

So, to put it into a solid question, which one of these options best supports the artist? Is there a more direct path?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal questions are off-topic.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya It's not really a question about any laws in specific - which was is legal or illegal, nah its more about which of the (assumed legal) ways is the best, or in other words, how me (a music fan) can access the music in the best music industry specific way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to this question because in most case, the answer would be "it depends". Exact numbers are obscure and depend on the artist, the selling platform, negociations... nothing is disclosed.

However, the most plausible answer I could suggest, is to go on the artist website and choose the selling service that is upper on the list (I logically believe that artists would suggest the selling service that they prefer up on the list).

In your case, it would be Deezer for streaming and iTunes store for download.

Comment: Another idea I've read often is to go to the artist's site and buy merch.